# An unwanted label appears around the leaflet map within shiny context

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Using leaflet, I have created the below pretty map within the shiny context. As shown in the image below, a label within a box (Intelectual Disability) appears around the map. It disappears when I click somewhere on the page, however, I was wondering to know why this happens and how can I avoid this?

Thanks,

Nader

[image]

Comment: Please share your code and / or from where you get the data. What is the left screenshot?

Comment: Maybe you're doing something that generates a spurious mouse event that results in a pop-up being displayed when the map is first generated.  But, as @FalkeDesign says, without your code we can only speculate.